# How can I run code every time a form appears (after being hidden instead of closed)?

Tags: vba, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, textbox

I am building a program that allows you to build a custom PC. Every time a user chooses a part to add to their list, the program returns to a form containing their list. I need the program to check for compatibility issues every time this list form appears. How can I run a block of code every time a form is shown?
The form does not get closed, it only gets hidden.

Comment: Look at the events of the form  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=netframework-4.7.2   maybe the Activate event. But its up to you to make an effort at research.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Visual Studio 17, if you double click your user form in the Designer mode you'll be taken to the code view and a sub will be created saying something like `Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`. Anything you put in this sub will run when the form loads.